# Blank white screen of magento admin after upgrade

Tags: admin, upgrade

I have just upgraded my magento site from 1.7.0.2 to latest version and when i visit my frontend, it is working fine but when I try to open admin panel, it shows nothing and display white screen.

I used following in index.php file to see any error but nothing is appearing still.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Please help me

Comment: Please go yourMagentoDir/var/report  and check the error file  and here magento print the error

Comment: There is no any "report" folder there but "log" folder in which one file created "system.log". In this file there is a statement "2015-06-22T05:19:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Controller Predispatch dispatched..."

Comment: you need to open your servers error log.

Comment: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento Store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a minute to figure out. I had to use a tool called beyond compare to fix it.

I did the upgrade using the "magento connect" via the admin. However this caused several issues. I upgraded 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.2

To fix this, you need to download the 1.9.2.2 CE from the magento site, then compare your directory structure to the files you just downloaded. You'll notice that many rogue directories have been created as file names (example: filename.php is actually a directory) You need to delete the directories and then copy the correct "file" over. You'll also notice that several hundred other files did not copy over. You'll need to copy those over too.

Long story short, don't use the magento connect upgrade, do it manually from the download.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty standard Connect heartburn... Also, Google Checkout was discontinued somewhere along the line so if going into System=>Configuration white screens the backend (1.9 stubs GoogleCheckout so only the Model is left, remove all GoogleCheckout/etc/*.xml files except config.xml)

Answer (score 8):

Below steps helped me to get the admin panel back after upgrade.

1. Download the targeted version of Magento.
2. In your instance, update following directories by copying from the downloaded version. `app/design/adminhtml` and `skin/adminhtml`.
3. Clear `var/cache` directory.

Comment: This is the correct solution :) Fixed my very same issue.

Answer (score 0):

just remove all files except config.xml in app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc